# Sqlite way to copy in a database only the distinct data present in another database

Tags: database, sqlite

Say I have two databases with the same structure but containing different data
A containing 1+2+3 as data spread on different tables;
B containing 1+2+3+4 as data spread on different tables;

Is there a way to find 4 and copy it into A?

Something like copying the distinct data only.

I was thinking about a way to
1) compare A and B; 
2) find the differences;
3) insert the differences in A;

dump A - dump B - diff the dumps - patch diff to A - feed to sqlite

but this approach doesn't seem to work.
patch gives troubles (offset lines)

Any idea? 
I have very little experience in programming, any suggestion is appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: You could get the table hashes if '4' references a table, that A does not contain. If both databases have the same tables which may or may not have different entries it will involve iterating over them I would guess.

Comment: You might get more traction asking in the DBA SE.

Comment: "If both databases have the same tables which may or may not have different entries"  this is the case "it will involve iterating over them" means?

Answer (score 0):

Use [EXCEPT](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_select.html#compound) to remove duplicate rows:

```
INSERT INTO A.MyTable
SELECT * FROM B.MyTable
EXCEPT
SELECT * FROM A.MyTable;
```

Comment: Thanks, but I don't know which table contains different data.

Comment: And why would that be a problem?

Comment: With your code shall I not define in which table insert data and from which table taking them?

Comment: Yes. Just do this for all tables.

Comment: Thanks! Anyway I thought there may be a way to make it in a faster way! something like doing it on the entire db at once.